# Cannot insert duplicate key in CRM 2011 Plugin import?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

I have exported the plugins from prod server, and getting the following error message when importing into the test server.

> Unhandled Exception: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
>   Server was unable to process request.
>
> Detail:
>
> `0x80040237`
>
> Cannot insert duplicate key.
>
> Platform
>
> at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage
>   message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean
>   asyncCall)
>
> at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] parameters)
>
> at PluginRegistrationTool.CrmSdk.CrmService.Create(BusinessEntity
>   entity)
>
> at
>   PluginRegistrationTool.RegistrationHelper.RegisterAssembly(CrmOrganization
>   org, String pathToAssembly, CrmPluginAssembly assembly)
>
> at
>   PluginRegistrationTool.ImportExport.ImportSolution(CrmOrganization
>   org, ICollection`1 assemblies, ICollection`1 checkedTreeNodes,
>   IDictionary`2 pathList)
>
> at PluginRegistrationTool.ImportExportForm.btnExecute_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

On your test server check if plugins/steps/images by the same name are already existing. If yes, then delete them first before attempting the import.

I would recommend that you delete all registered plungins first before attempting to import.

Comment: Don't delete.. disable! It's often good practice to disable workflows as well to speed up imports but it entirely depends on your system design whether or not it is safe to disable plugins/workflows.

Answer (score 0):

[image]When you create a new plugin Visual Studio will automatically create the step/class name for you based on the Pipeline Stage (Pre-Validation, Pre-Operation, Post-Operation)  the Primary Entity (Contact, Organization) and the Message (Create, Update, etc)  For example, PostContactUpdate or PreOrganizationUpdate, so if you happen to be making another plugin with same message, pipeline stage and primary entity and you accepted the default class names that could explain why you are getting the error. Changing the class name and redeploying should fix it for you.